# Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "undefined"

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, angular-ui-router

I'm getting the following error when pressing the **View Post** link *(navigating to the* `posts.postview` *state)* in my Angular, ui-router & Firebase app:

`Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"`

On the main page of the app I have a list of 4 posts. The data from these posts are being fetched from Firebase. Each post has a link to the post page via a **View Post** link like in the following screenshot:

[image]

When I click the **View Post** link I see the post page load but I will get the above Firebase error and the Firebase data will not populate the template *(postview.tpl.html)* as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I have an updated minimal version of the app running here in Plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/bGqFZ2VI7OSrO0myDjkq?p=preview

Also, here is the controller and service files related to fetching the post data:

---

**postview.ctrl.js**

```
app.controller('PostViewCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, Post, Auth) {
    $scope.post = Post.get($routeParams.postId);
    $scope.comments = Post.comments($routeParams.postId);

    $scope.user = Auth.user;
    $scope.signedIn = Auth.signedIn;

});
```

**post.serv.js**

```
app.factory('Post', function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    var posts = $firebase(ref.child('posts')).$asArray();

    var Post = {
        all: posts,
        get: function (postId) {
            return $firebase(ref.child('posts').child(postId)).$asObject();
        }
    };

    return Post;
});
```

---

Any ideas on what's wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what to do in that plunker. Can you reduce it to a **minimal** reproduction of your problem? Also: please include the relevant code from the plunkr in your question.

Comment: Sorry for being too vague with the post. I have updated the Plunker and post to illustrate my issue more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I got the individual post page to populate the template with the proper data from Firebase by changing`routeParams` to `stateParams` in the postview.ctrl.js since that is what ui-router needs to function. More info on stateParams can be found here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service

The working postview.ctrl.js

```
app.controller('PostViewCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, Post, Auth) {
    $scope.post = Post.get($stateParams.postId);
    $scope.comments = Post.comments($stateParams.postId);

    $scope.user = Auth.user;
    $scope.signedIn = Auth.signedIn;

});
```

And the working Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/mnBYG1A1MEEv6gINRBbb?p=preview